# Error while opening Django admin: "Error at /admin/ Incorrect padding"

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I was making a web app using Django. I was using Django 3.0.7 for the sake.
Then I upgraded to Django 3.1.1.
When I reinstalled Django 3.0.7 I am unable to open Django Admin. While I try to get into my Django admin an error shows up saying:

```
Error at /admin/
Incorrect padding
Exception Location: ...\python\python38\lib\base64.py in b64decode, line 87
```

Comment: my answer on another SO thread (related to django ugrade) my help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64588561/12368419

Comment: So do I need to run ```python manage.py collectstatic``` or ```python manage.py collectstatic --clear```..?

Comment: use the command with `--clear` option.

Comment: It's not working in Chrome but working in Edge. probably due to caching.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in Chrome by deleting any cookies relating to my Django development server port.